# What is meant by "Junior 3D printer"?

Tags: creality-ender-3

I am looking to buy an Ender-3 Pro, but the place I'm looking to buy from has this picture:

[image: Confusing 3D printer publicity photo]

My question is, what is meant by "Junior" in the name?

I'm just wondering if this means it's an alternative kind of version for kids or something, or if it's just the name of that type of 3D Printer (e.g. in the way you might have a Junior Hacksaw or something)? I.e. is this the normal Ender V3 Pro?

Comment: I'm not aware of it having any common meaning or of there being a different "junior" model it could apply too. Pretty sure the vendor just lacks communication skills promoting the product they're trying to sell and is using a word that's pointless and confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as a *Junior*<sup>1</sup>, you can see the official Creality range of FDM printers on the [FDM 3D PRINTER](https://www.creality.com/product/fdm-3d-printer) page, on their web site.

Upon a cursory comparison of the photo it is one of these:

- Ender-3 Max 3D Printer
- Ender-3 Pro 3D Printer
- Ender-3 3D Printer

However, the first one can be discounted as the spool holder is missing. So this leaves the last two.

Finally, the biggest clue is in the photo itself, as the name is written in the last line: [***Ender-3 Pro***](https://www.creality.com/goods-detail/ender-3-pro-3d-printer).

Nevertheless, given the seller's random "junior" labelling, it is not entirely guaranteed that the printer is, in fact, a Pro.

Unless they are super cheap or a renowned seller, then it is probably best to avoid purchasing anything from them. Or contact the seller to see if they would clarify their misleading advert.

---

<sup>1</sup> The term *junior* could be an indication of the base level entry of the printer, or a reference to its build size, which, while not small and is pretty standard, it is not as large as some of the more pricey Creality models.

Comment: ...but the ender3 is larger than the Prusa I3 it was originally derived from.

Answer (score 1):

That is an Ender 3, with the vertical PSU, the older interface, and many tweaks like the drawer and filament loading knob isn't present.

Consider the Ender 3 V2 instead, which is an iteration on the same basic design and is newer.

Personally I found it cheaper to buy the V2 direct from Creality's website than to buy the older model from a local or other online seller, and it had free freight from China, and arrived in about 3 weeks.